# Dynamically override class methods based on an instantiating variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to implement a class that imports/overrides methods from different files based on an instantiating variable, with that variable directing Python to different scripts(/mixin classes) for the methods to override, based on the variable.

So if I instantiated `MyClass("foo")`, it would include the functions from `./foo.py` as class methods. Alternatively, if I instantiated `MyClass("bar")`, it would include the functions of `./bar.py` as class methods

To make clearer what I mean, see my example below. I'm fully aware that what I show below is not valid Python, but it hopefully conveys my meaning.

I'm unconcerned whether `foo` and `bar` are written as classes in their own right, or a file full of plain Python function definitions, but I've used the latter in my example.

---

Say I had two scripts `foo.py` and `bar.py`, comprising in their entirety:

foo.py:

```
method1(self):
   return "Method 1 Overridden from foo.py"
```

bar.py:

```
method2(self):
   return "Method 2 Overridden from bar.py"
```

And my general class set up like:

```
def BaseClass():
   def __init__:
      #instantiate class
   def method1(self):
      return "Method 1 - Not Overridden"
   def method2(self):
      return "Method 2 - Not Overridden"

def DynamicClass(BaseClass):
   def __init__(self,configstring):
      super().__init__()
      override_methods(configstring)
```

And I would want output like:

```
>>> a = DynamicClass()
>>>a.method1()
Method 1 - Not Overridden
>>>a.method2()
Method 2 - Not Overridden

>>> b = DynamicClass("foo")
>>>b.method1()
Method 1 Overridden from foo.py
>>>b.method2()
Method 2 - Not Overridden

>>> c = DynamicClass("bar")
>>>c.method1()
Method 1 - Not Overridden
>>>c.method2()
Method 2 Overridden from bar.py
```

---

To explain a little more about the "Why" of my question:  I want to process a lot of data, and do different things based on what that data is.  The *steps* for working with the data are consistent (say there is a `pre-processing` step, a `notify-admins` step, a `main-processing` and a `garbage-collect` step), but what happens in each step is very different, depending on the data's `type`.

I want to implement a generic class, with each step encapsulated as a method, something like the below (only with more extensive default methods):

```
class BaseClass():
   def pre-processing(self):
      pass
   def notify-admins(self):
      send_email(addressee="admin@example.com",mailbody="Datatype {} submitted for processing".format(dataobject['type']))
   def main-processing(self):
      pass
   def garbage-collect(self):
      generic_garbagecollect(dataobject)

def DynamicClass(BaseClass):
   def __init__(self,dataobject):
      super().__init__()
      override_methods(dataobject['type'])
```

And then have various files overriding only the methods I need to override for each step:

```
foo.py
bar.py
```

And then instantiate the class using the data itelf as an argument:

```
processor = DynamicClass(dataobject)
processor.pre-processing()
processor.notify-admins()
processor.main-processing()
processor.garbage-collect()
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question, but is there a reason why you're using `DynamicClass` instead of creating `Foo` and `Bar` classes that directly inherit `BaseClass`?

Comment: Because I don't know a way to switch between calling `Foo` and `Bar` based on a variable.  Alain T.'s answer suggests a way to do it, if only I could get it to work...

Comment: If that's your actual issue, use a dictionary like: `d = {'foo': Foo, 'bar': Bar}` and instantiate the class based on the key: `var = 'foo'; instance = d['foo']()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the factory pattern.  What you should do is have each module define a sub class of the base class and "Register" themselves in a global dictionary (maintained in the module of the base class e.g. as a static variable).   Then, you can use the dictionary to obtain which subclass to instantiate based on whatever key allows you to identify your datatype.

Base class file:

```
# base.py

class Base:
    # ...

factory = dict()
```

subclass files:

```
# foo.py
import base

class Foo(base.Base):
    # override whatever you need

base.factory["FOO"] = Foo
```

...

```
# bar.py
import base 

class Bar(base.Base):
    # override whatever you need

base.factory["BAR"] = Bar
```

Calling code:

```
# mainProgram.py
import base
import foo
import bar

# ...
DataType   = "FOO"
DataObject = base.factory[DataType]()  # will create an instance of Foo
```

Comment: I follow the concept of what you are saying, but can't get the implementation to work.  Even with the minimal implementation given, the `import foo` throws `NameError: name 'Base' is not defined`.

Comment: I forgot to add import base in the subclass files